# What to do about users who search for spelling mistakes

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, serial-edits

I've just come across a user while reviewing suggested edits, having noticed they're correcting the same spelling error (namely *diferent*) - each of their edits is too minor because its generally only a title issue.

Is there a mechanism for detecting this kind of behaviour? It's somewhat annoying to have a review queue backed up with the same user making the same poor edit over and over (I'm guessing only for the rep), and it would be nice to know they'd get a message about the behaviour.

Comment: If rejecting the suggested edits doesn't help (enough rejected edits will result in a time-out for the user) then you can flag one of their posts for moderator attention. Use the "other" flag and clearly explain the situation. But only do so if the behaviour is particularly frequent and inappropriate.

Comment: I wonder if this kind of behaviour would be classes as _inappropriate_, I think it does mainly because it's taking up the time of the community needlessly

Comment: I have left a comment for this particular user, informing him he will have to focus on the full post. Let's see if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just caught one of those, and had to edit out a bunch of other stuff in the post.  He had only fixed 'diferent' in the title, so I marked it as unhelpful (unchecked the helpful box) when I did my edit.

It's fine to search for those kind of mistakes, but they should be fixing everything not just the sole spelling mistake.

Comment: Yep I started doing the same, I just don't see the value of searching for old posts with usually only 1 error

Comment: Well, there are probably tens of thousands of posts that need editing, so __any__ method that gives you a coordinated way to find them is probably not a bad thing.

Comment: I suppose, I just don't think it's good practise to just search for 1 spelling mistake and go on a spree fixing only that issue

Comment: @TomWalters It can be a nice way to generate a list of content that needs work. There's no immediate problem with that. As long as the user then focuses on correcting all issues in the post and not merely the one item he searched for.

Comment: @Tom Walters http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist could be a possible explanation/"value" behind searching old posts.

Answer (score 3):

If the edits are truly too minor you should be rejecting them.  Hopefully enough other users are also rejecting them, rather than accepting them; if that's the case, the user will eventually be banned from suggesting edits for 7 days once enough of their suggestions are rejected.

Other than that, no feedback will be given (automatically) to the user suggesting the edits.  If you wish, you can comment on a post that they have edited telling them that they should not be making minor edit suggestions and that they should be fixing all problems in a post they choose to edit.  You should ideally link to relevant FAQ/meta posts on the subject in such a comment.  Note that @ replies will notify anyone in the revision history, even though the autocomplete doesn't include people in the revision history that haven't commented, so the user will get a notification of your comment.

Comment: What if a user is banned for 7 days but does not come on the site for 8 days? Does that mean they never knew they were banned?

Comment: @0A0D Potentially, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Any positive edit is a good edit.

Always be improving the site's content in whatever manner you can, no matter how granular.

Comment: This is what the policy *should* be, but not what it actually is.  :/